# Implement the button on android surfaceview

Tags: android

I need to implement a button on Android `SurfaceView`, should I do this in layout (use CustomView and classic Button) or how can I do it? I need to listen to the two events `onTouchStart`/`onTouchDown` and `onTouchEnd`/`onTouchUp`... is it possible?

Comment: Just put a button in your layout.

Comment: XML file: Custom view, framelayout as root element

Comment: and how do I listen to those events (onTouchDown and onTouchUp)?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 no I need onTouchDown (when the button is being pressed) and then onTouchUp (when the button is being released)

Comment: Do you need it fed with a silver spoon??? onClickListener contains a view which you can then use to access the state if the button

Comment: :D nice comment, thank you, didn't know that